# In the given code, whichever block i place first sequentially returns a result while the one i place [continued in desc]

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, readlines

**[continuation]**-  second returns the result as zero, why and how do make both read functions work with the same file name?

**CODE:**

```
myfile=open(r'C:\Users\win8\Documents\Cs Record\trust.txt','r')

   **#number of lines in the file:**

r2=myfile.readlines()

nol=len(r2)

print('The number of lines in trust.txt is',nol)

**#size of the file:**

r1=myfile.read()

sof=len(r1)

print('The size of trust.txt is',sof,'bytes')

myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Either rewind file pointer before reading it again using `myfile.seek(0)`

Or better use

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
# file is closed now
```